# Can we simplify the classification of infinite Dedekind-finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: set-theory, infinity

In ZF, does there exist a bijection between the infinite subsets X of $\mathbb{N}$ for which there exists no injection $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow X$ and the set of infinite Dedekind-finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$?
If so, can we construct one and what would it look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes, for the disappointing reason that both families are empty.

There are no infinite Dedekind-finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, since it is well ordered. If $X\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ is infinite, then $X$ is equinumerous with $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Yes, I understand. In my enthusiasm I glossed over one of the basics. Still, I'm curious. Are there infinite non well ordered sets we can substitute for $\mathbb{N}$ such that the answer remains yes? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The main thing to say is that being infinite and having no injection from $\mathbb{N}$ is the same thing as being infinite but Dedekind finite.